# How to replace with one sed command first n letter to uppercase

Tags: regex, sed, scripting

I would like to replace with one sed command first n letter to uppercase.

Example 'madrid' to 'MADrid'. (n=3)

I know how to change first letter to uppercase with this command:

```
    sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\U\1/g"
```

but I dont know how to change this command for my problem.

I tried to change

```
    sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\U\1/g"
```

to

```
    sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\U\3/g"
```

but this didnt work. Also, I googled and searched on this site but exact answer with my problem I couldnt find.

Thank you.

Comment: Kudos, this is a perfect example for any beginner in SO to look at on how to ask.

Answer (score 4):

I infer from your use of `\U` that you're using *GNU* `sed`:

```
n=3
echo 'madrid' | sed -r 's/\<(.{'"$n"'})/\U\1/g'  # -> 'MADrid'
```

- I've omitted the unnecessary `-e` option
- I have added `-r` to enable support for *extended* regular expressions, which have more familiar syntax and also offer more features.
- I'm using a *single-quoted* `sed` script with a shell-variable value *spliced in* so as to avoid confusion between what the shell expands up front and what is interpreted by `sed` itself.
- `\<` is used instead of `\b`, because unlike the latter it only matches at the *start* of a word.<sup>Thanks, [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte)</sup>

The above replaces any 3 characters at the start of a word, however.

To limit it to *at most* `$n` *letters*:

```
sed -r 's/\<([[:alpha:]]{1,'"$n"'})/\U\1/g'
```

---

As for what you've tried:

The `\3` in your attempt `sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\U\3/g"` refers to the *3rd capture group* (parenthesized subexpression, `(...)`) in the regex (which doesn't exist), it does *not* refer to 3 repetitions.

Instead, you have to make sure that your one and only capture group (which you can reference as `\1` in the substitution) itself captures as many characters as desired - which is what the `{<n>}` quantifier is for; the related `{<m>,<n>}` construct matches a *range* of repetitions.

Comment: *"... and also offer more features"*: in particular the word boundary `\b`, but note that using `\<` in place of `\b` may be more precise in particular if the string contains more than one word separated with, at least, n non-word characters (or less since you use `{1,n}`). But it doesn't matter since these non-word characters don't have a case.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r 's/[a-z]/&\n/'"$n"';s/^([^\n]*)\n/\U\1/' file
```

Where `$n` is the first n letters. Putting the question of word boundaries aside this converts `n` letters of `a-z` consecutive or non-consecutive to upper case i.e. `A-Z`

N.B. this is two sed commands not one!